# Replacing Azure ACS authentication with Active Directory authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5.1, azure-active-directory

Currently in my mvc 5 application we have implement Azure ACS authentication , we would like to replace it with Active Directory authentication, how do we do that?

Comment: MSDN may help, perhaps?